# Laravel Administrator package relationship error

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, ardent

My Ardent model has a has_one relationship like this

```
public static $relationsData = array(
'organization'  => array(self::HAS_ONE, 'Organization', 'foreignKey' => 'party_id'),
);
```

Now, my Laravel Administrator package's model config file have column configuration like this

```
'columns' => array(
'id',
'organization' => array(
    'title' => "Organization",
    'relationship' => 'organization', //this is the name of the Eloquent relationship method!
    'select' => "(:table).organization_name",
),
'address' 
),
```

Now, it is throwing an error like this

Maximum function nesting level of '100' reached, aborting!
Open: C:\xampp\htdocs\hrms\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\Str.php

```
* Convert a value to studly caps case.
*
* @param  string  $value
* @return string
*/
public static function studly($value)
{
    $value = ucwords(str_replace(array('-', '_'), ' ', $value));

return str_replace(' ', '', $value);
```

Comment: I responded on github which can be found [here](https://github.com/FrozenNode/Laravel-Administrator/issues/748#issuecomment-62586141)

Answer (score 0):

(I answered this [here](https://github.com/FrozenNode/Laravel-Administrator/issues/748#issuecomment-63155327) and now I'm just whoring for reputation!)

Using the solution given by [@bobiasg](https://github.com/bobiasg) in issue [#418](https://github.com/FrozenNode/Laravel-Administrator/issues/418), I was able to solve the error. This is in Administrator/DataTable/Columns/Relationships/BelongsTo.php:71

```
//if the model method doesn't exist for any of the pieces along the way, exit out
if ((!method_exists($models[$i], $rel) && !is_callable(array($models[$i], $rel))) || !is_a($models[$i]->{$rel}(), self::BELONGS_TO))
{
    throw new \InvalidArgumentException("The '" . $this->getOption('column_name') . "' column in your " . $this->config->getOption('name') .
        " model configuration needs to be either a belongsTo relationship method name or a sequence of them connected with a '.'");
}
```